# Remove File Name from gcc/g++ Compile Result

Tags: regex, linux, gcc, g++

I want to remove file names from gcc/g++ compile error messages.

When I run `gcc myfolder/temp.c`, the result is:

```
myfolder/temp.c:5:1: error: unknown type name ‘voi’
myfolder/temp.c:87:6: error: conflicting types for ‘max’
myfolder/temp.c:5:5: note: previous declaration of ‘max’ was here
```

But I want this:

```
5:1: error: unknown type name ‘voi’
87:6: error: conflicting types for ‘max’
5:5: note: previous declaration of ‘max’ was here
```

Is there a gcc flag for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there is an option for this but you could achieve the same result using standard utilities. For instance with `cut(1)`

```
 gcc -c myfolder/temp.c 2>&1 | cut -d: -f2-
```

Comment: Thanks.
Now I want to decrease line numbers by two. I want to change above result to:
    `3:1: error: unknown type name ‘voi’
    85:6: error: conflicting types for ‘max’
    3:5: note: previous declaration of ‘max’ was here`
How can I do this?

Comment: @MJNaderi that would require several operations: line splitting, arithmetics and concatenation, too much for a standard pipeline filter, but a few lines of `perl` or `awk` script would do that. E.g.
`awk -F: '/^[^:]+:[1-9][0-9]*:/ {printf( "%d", $2 + 2) ; for(i=3;i<= NF;i++) {printf( ":%s", $i) ;}  printf ("\n"); }'`